# Breaking down the phrase 俺は学校にいたはずだ

Tags: translation, conjugations

I came across the phrase

> 俺は学校にいたはずだ

in a comic I'm trying to translate.

I understand the statement means something like "I should be at school!". It looks like 俺は学校に is setting up the speaker as the topic, and that the speaker should be doing something at school.

But the difficult part for me is the verb, いたはずだ. I want to say it is a very casual conjugation of the verb, いく, but I can only guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phrase means 'I must have been at school.' いた is the perfectly normal past tense of いる, and はず is not 'should' as in 'obliged to' but 'should' as in 'it's probable that ...', for example 'By the time you get there it should already be ready.'